# SQLITE: Select row ID based on only when the column all the values are same

Tags: select, sqlite

I have a table where more than one rows with same `ttid`. I would like to get `ttid` rows based on status column is `done`.

```
tb  tbid    ttid    status
-----------------------------
216 6   5   done
216 6   5   running
216 7   5   preparing
217 11  10  done
217 11  10  done
218 12  11  done
218 12  11  running
212 15  14  done
212 15  14  running
220 17  15  done
220 17  15  done
```

I wanted to have the following rows only:

```
tb      tbid    ttid    status
--------------------------------
217     11      10      done
220     17      15      done
```

I have tried the following query but it gives wrong info for `tb: 216`, because two different `tbid`.

```
select tb,tbid,tbid,status FROM tt 
status in ('done')
```

Could you please help how to get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

> I should not get the result of ttid 5 because it has status as
>   'preparing'. I should get ttids results only when all the statuses are
>   'done'.

*To get only the ones where done is found twice and no other statuses are found:*

```
SELECT tb,  tbid, ttid,status 
FROM  test t1
WHERE status = 'done'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t2 where t2.status != 'done' and t1.ttid = t2.ttid)
GROUP BY  tb,tbid,ttid,status
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/759dvP74jxW4HG3rvVi3uD/5)

Or

```
SELECT ttid,status 
FROM test t1
WHERE status = 'done'  
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t2 where t2.status != 'done' and t1.ttid = t2.ttid)
GROUP BY  ttid,status
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/759dvP74jxW4HG3rvVi3uD/6)

The reasoning for adding it to the group by or applying a function:

if `tb` or `tbid` can be different for the same 'done' `status` and the same `ttid`, which one do you choose? Do you choose the smallest, the biggest, ...?

An example of what happens if this is true and it is not added to a `group by` or function:

[DB-Fiddle that fails](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGWcHXziiMAgYUBN27qbY3/0)

Comment: I will try your example, btw I choose biggest one.

Comment: Its not working when two different `tbid` presented in table. see my DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/759dvP74jxW4HG3rvVi3uD/4

Comment: @MohanRagav what do you mean not working?  It gives a result for ttid 5, 10 and 15 which seems like what you want to me, since 5 has two 'done' statuses.

Comment: I should not get the result of ttid 5 because it has status as 'preparing'. I should get `ttid`s results only when all the statuses are 'done'.

Comment: @MohanRagav alright I think I get what you want, adding an update

Comment: @MohanRagav, good to hear :) no problem!